# With Visio 2016, how can I add a clear formatting function?

Tags: microsoft-visio

With Word and Excel, there;s a function that allows me to clear the formatting of a whatever I highlight.  How can I accomplish the same result with Visio 2016?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Clear Text Formatting, but it is hidden.

File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> All Commands

Comment: For more information on customizing ribbon in Visio, read [Customize the ribbon in Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31).